# Mysql syntax error creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

This is driving me nuts.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CalcularCRTarea` (Id_Tarea INT, OUT crTarea decimal(12, 4))
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE _id BIGINT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Id FROM Tarea_Frente where Id_Item_Tarea = Id_Tarea;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;
  OPEN cur;
  testLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO _id;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE testLoop;
    ELSE 
        CALL CalcularCRFrente(_id, @suma);
        SET crTarea = crTarea + @suma;
    END IF;
  END LOOP testLoop;

  CLOSE cur;      
END;
```

`phpmyadmin` returns me

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

that would be the line

```
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
```

what's wrong here ? I tried with several minor changes and I'm getting always the same error. I checked the documentation and I'm not seeing what's the syntax error.
I know this is a silly error but I'm stucked with this like a half an hour.
Is a cursor that iterates each row and executes a stored procedure for each one; I've done it with stored functions (and it worked like a charm) but at the time to publish in the server I saw that my shared hosting doesn't suppor stored functions, only stored procedures :( So it's the best way I've found.

Comment: I tested on MySQL 5.6.16 and it works fine with no error. Are you sure you posted the right code? Any hidden weird whitespace characters that got filtered out when you posted here?

Comment: It is the right code. I thought on hidden weird whitespace, but I deleted everyone after each ";". I'm using MySQL 5.5.35

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing custom `delimiter` instruction.

As you missed it, engine tried to compile the statements when it found the first default statement terminator, the semicolon `;`.  And hence the exception.

Place your entire routine in between:

```
-- define the delimiter
delimiter //


--- place here your stored procedure

-- and lastly following line
//

-- reset the delimiter
delimiter ;
```

Comment: great, it worked. I thought it was not neccesary, as in some cases I could create stored without using this. Why is neccesary?

Comment: I guess this must be the correct reason, Did you guess or try?

Comment: @Gonzalo.-: Usually stored procedures, including triggers comprise a set of executable statements. But they all are part of a single body but not individual statements. To group them we need to instruct the engine with a new statement or block terminator. It is done using `delimiter`.

Comment: @Gonzalo.-: And usually most GUI based SQL interpreters allow you not to use them. You can also see on [*SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that it has a drop down list to chose custom delimiter to use on your statemenets.

Comment: Yes, phpmyadmin has a delimiter option on the above, I just saw it