# Error in mysql while creating a trigger

Tags: mysql

I have two table stock detail and purchase.

When I'm trying to create a trigger on the table purchase it will seems an error that

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 "
```

Hear is my code

```
create TRIGGER afterinsert after insert on purchase for each row
BEGIN 
set @qnty=(select quantity from stock_detail where brand_name = new.brand);
if(@qnty>=1) then
update stock_detail set quantity=@qnty+new.quanty;
end if;
END;
```

Comment: I dont see any delimiter for the trigger. If you write the trigger on mysql CLI then you need to set the delimiter other than the default one which is `;` so you need `delimiter //` at the top and finally `END;// delimiter ;`

Comment: are you setting the delimiter before creating the trigger? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23160180/767881

Comment: can u correctly write my codeing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delimiter //
create TRIGGER afterinsert after insert on purchase for each row
BEGIN 
set @qnty=(select quantity from stock_detail where brand_name = new.brand);
if(@qnty>=1) then
update stock_detail set quantity=@qnty+new.quanty;
end if;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

For more info refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html