# Create mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, procedures

I'm trying to create procedure in mysql database this procedure will move accounts from table to another
this is my procedure but I have error with syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE radius.archive_acct()
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO radacctold
 SELECT * FROM radacct
 WHERE acctstoptime > 0
 AND date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
 DELETE FROM radacct
WHERE acctstoptime > 0
AND date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
END
```

this is the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

Comment: Are you sure fields in both the tables are same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the normal delimiter to some other value and then create and end the procedure and reset the delimiter.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE radius.archive_acct()
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO radacctold
 SELECT * FROM radacct
 WHERE acctstoptime > 0 AND date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
 DELETE FROM radacct
 WHERE acctstoptime > 0
 AND date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

For more insights see: [Getting Started with MySQL Stored Procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures structures are made for supporting multiple executable statements.
And each statements needs a terminator, which is by default semicolon. `;`.

It is required to instruct mysql engine to *stop execute immediately* every terminated statement, until the body structure is processed compiled.

We need a `DELIMITER` statement to suppress the default terminator temporarily.
Your code did not use such `DELIMITER`.

Following example will help fixing your code.

```
-- define the delimiter
delimiter //


--- place here your stored procedure

-- and lastly following line
//

-- reset the delimiter
delimiter ;
```

Read my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23160180/767881