# MariaDB Stored Procedure Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Having an issue with my syntax for a stored procedure, using the error messages I'm having some issues narrowing down where I've gone wrong. Sorry for such a simple question, I don't do DBA things that often.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `addPlayerLog`(
IN `steamid` VARCHAR(255),
IN `category` VARCHAR(255),
IN `ipaddress` VARCHAR(255),
IN `message` VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE rowcount INT DEFAULT 0;

IF category = "connect" THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO rowcount
    FROM players
    WHERE players.steamid = steamid;
    
    IF rowcount = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO players (players.steamid)
    VALUES (steamid);
    ENDIF;
    
    IF rowcount = 1 THEN
        UPDATE players
        SET lastseen = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
        WHERE players.steamid = steamid;
    ENDIF;
    
ENDIF;

INSERT INTO log_player (log_player.steamid, log_player.category, log_player.ipaddress, log_player.message)
VALUES (steamid, category, ipaddress, message);

END;
```

Error message it produces is "SQL Syntax Error near " at line 8" which is the declare line.

To me it seems very straight forward, any help should be greatly appreciated.

Note: MariaDB Version 10.3.29 if that matters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql syntax error creating stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160044/mysql-syntax-error-creating-stored-procedure)

Comment: Did you include a command to change the delimiter? If you didn't then mysql will assume that the first semicolon marks the end of the query. Try adding `DELIMITER $$` as the first line and `DELIMITER ;` as the last line.

Comment: Unrelated to syntax error, [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) can perform the 'log_player' functionality. Use [insert on duplicate key update](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/) for your `category = "connect"` sql statement.